# Unable to load WebRTC audio track into HTML audio element

Tags: javascript, webrtc, jssip

I can't manage to load the WebRTC audio track into the HTML audio to play, it looks like the `src` source does not update.

You will find the implementation in JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/redvivi/ut3pgcnq/

Here is the code sections of interest:

**HTML**

```html
    <audio id="remoteAudio" controls></audio>
```

**JS**

```js
function attachRemoteStream(session) {
  // Fetch the existing audio element or create a new one

  session.connection.ontrack = (event) => {
    if (event.track.kind === 'audio') {
      if (event.streams.length > 0) {
        remoteAudio.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      } else {
        const stream = new MediaStream([event.track]);
        remoteAudio.srcObject = stream;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```js
  phone.on('newRTCSession',function(ev){
    var newSession = ev.session;
    [...]
    session.on('peerconnection', (e) => { // peerconnection is RTCPeerConnection instance
      if(session.direction === 'incoming'){
        attachRemoteStream(session);
        remoteAudio.load();
        remoteAudio.play();        
      } else {
        session.connection.addEventListener('track', function (e) {
          // set remote audio stream
          remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.streams[0]);
          remoteAudio.load();
          remoteAudio.play();
        });
      }
    });
  })
```

I have also confirmed that the WebRTC stream actually returns  data (cf below)
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your code for demonstration purposes, if both caller and callee are using the Chrome browser, it works.

```
session.connection.ontrack = e => {
  msglog("connection");
  let qq = document.getElementById("qq");
  msglog("event key:" + JSON.stringify(e));
  qq.srcObject = e.streams[0];
}

https://jsfiddle.net/0z5srjue/ (caller)

session.connection.ontrack = e => {
  msglog("connection");
  let qq = document.getElementById("qq");
  msglog("event key:" + JSON.stringify(e));
  qq.srcObject = e.streams[0];
}

https://jsfiddle.net/4x8L9pw6/ (callee)
```

Usage:
Browse the fiddle, and then click the start button.

When both parties show the word "registered" in the textarea, you can go to the caller browser, and click the "call" button, then you can listen to the audio from the caller side on the callee side.

PS: In the callee, I have added the "autoplay" attribute to the audio tag, so that it can play the audio once the stream arrived.

Comment: Omg it works @TheKNVB! You are a genius! How can I send you a coffee!?

Answer (score 1):

You may replace the following statements:

```
      remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.streams[0]);
      remoteAudio.load();
      remoteAudio.play();
```

with

```
remoteAudio.srcObject=e.streams[0];
```

And replace

```
const stream = new MediaStream([event.track]);
remoteAudio.srcObject = stream;
```

with

```
remoteAudio.srcObject = event.track;
```

Comment: Thanks @The KNVB. I have implemented your proposal in https://jsfiddle.net/redvivi/ut3pgcnq/66/, unfortunately, still no sound is heard :/

Comment: It is because I am currently cannot connect to wss://sip.iptel.org:8081.
So, can you  use console.log to print the e.stream[0] and event.track to show what are they?

Comment: Hey @The KNVB, I have updated the implementation at this address https://jsfiddle.net/redvivi/ut3pgcnq/68/ with your proposal. Unfortunately, the results are the same :/
Normally after 1-2 min the wss://sip.iptel.org:8081 accepts the connection again.

Comment: Do I need a username and password to make the jsfiddle link working properly?

Comment: No. JSFiddle should load, SIP registers on loading, and hitting the call button should do the trick. Do you have any error?

Comment: Do you have another target to call? otherwise just sip:redvivi@iptel.org calls sip:redvivi@iptel.org.

Comment: Just set another up @The KNVB - target=sip:redvivi1@iptel.org | password=password

Answer (score -1):

have you tried the PeerJS library?
It is simpler than JSSIP.

Comment: Not yet. Does this mean that JSSIP implementation is impossible/non-functional ?

Comment: I am not sure about it, I cannot make JSSIP works in my environment only. And I have tried the PeerJS library before, and it is working properly in my environment. The PeerJS documentation is clearer than JSSIP.

Comment: Do you have a working implementation on JSFiddle by any chance ?

Comment: Would you tell me how to use your JSFiddle?

Comment: You have to click on “Fork” in the menu bar to create a new version. You will get a unique link that may be shared.

Comment: If you mean how to make it work, upon loading the SIP user is automatically registered. Hitting on call will target a fake user "music" automatically playing music upon connection.

Comment: Unfortunately,after I click the call button no music is  played.

Comment: Yeah, hence the issue I am trying to solve. However chrome://webrtc-internals shows there is audio streaming coming through.